# Show loading screen in cocos2d-x android

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

My cocos2d-x game takes too long to start on android (almost 4-6 seconds). I am ok with this delay but while the game is loading I would like to show a loading/splash screen. I have created a splash scene for this but it always displays after cocos2d-x has loaded completely (ie. after the delay). How can I show a splash scene immediately on start up before cocos2d-x has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to start the splash activity in Android first while running a thread behind to load the content of cocos2dx.
After completion, you need the callback to Android native and switch the activity of cocos2dx to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a detailed example of adding a splash scene in cocos2d-x 3.4 in my other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29666673/1446995