# Create Splash screen in cocos 2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

Hello I am creating an game in cocos2d-x and when I am scheduling an event on splash screen for run game .It shows compilation error (in expansion of macro 'schedule_selector')

Following is my code for this

Splash.h

```
#ifndef SPLASH_H_
#define SPLASH_H_
#include "cocos2d.h"
class CCSplashLayer : public cocos2d::CCLayer {
private :
     void runGame();
public:
    static cocos2d::CCScene* createScene();
    virtual bool init();
    CREATE_FUNC(CCSplashLayer);
};
#endif /* SPLASH_H_ */
```

And SplashScene.cpp

```
#include "splash.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"

USING_NS_CC;

bool CCSplashLayer::init() {
    if (!Layer::init()) {
        return false;
    }
    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();

    auto sprite = Sprite::create("splash.png");
    sprite->setScale(Director::getInstance()->getContentScaleFactor());
    sprite->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width / 2,visibleSize.height/2));
    this->addChild(sprite, 0);

    //This line cause problem show i symbol on this line in eclipse
    this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(CCSplashLayer::runGame),4.0f);

    return true;
}

Scene* CCSplashLayer::createScene() {
    auto scene = CCScene::create();
    auto layer = CCSplashLayer::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}

void CCSplashLayer::runGame(){
     auto scene = HelloWorld::createScene();
     Director::getInstance()->setDepthTest(true);
     TransitionScene *transition = TransitionScene::create(0.5f, scene);
     Director::getInstance()->pushScene(transition);
}
```

Comment: what's the exact error message?

Comment: Schedule event line shows i icon in eclipse and show this message on hover ** in expansion of macro 'schedule_selector'**

Comment: is it just a warning or an actual error? Post a screenshot. You aren't really giving us enough information to tell you definitevely.

Comment: You can find a detailed example of adding a splash scene in cocos2d-x 3.4 in my other post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29666673/1446995

Answer (score 0):

`schedule_selector` takes function pointer which needs a float argument for time.

Change method `CCSplashLayer::runGame()` to `CCSplashLayer::runGame(float dt)` in defination and declaration.

Also you are pushing a scene over splash scene, which is not recommended way for splash scene. You must replace splash scene with new scene because we never need to display splash again in game unless there is specific design requirement of game.

Answer (score 0):

Try this macro:

```
#define CCDL_PERFORM_SELECTOR( __OWNER__, __DELAY__, __CALLFUNC_SELECTOR__ ) \
    __OWNER__->runAction( cocos2d::Sequence::create( \
        cocos2d::DelayTime::create( __DELAY__ ), \
        cocos2d::CallFunc::create( CC_CALLBACK_0( __CALLFUNC_SELECTOR__,__OWNER__) ), \
        nullptr )); \
```

(source: https://github.com/duksel/Cocos2dx-DukselLib/blob/master/Cocos2dx-DukselLib/DukselMacros.h#L70-L74)

Allow to use for any CCNode (+subclass) instance.
In your case will be:

```
bool CCSplashLayer::init()
{
    CCDL_PERFORM_SELECTOR( this, 4.f, CCSplashLayer::runGame );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try like this...
in init method,

```
this->runAction(CCSequence::create(CCDelayTime::create(4.0f),
                CCCallFuncN::create(this,callfuncN_selector(CCSplashLayer::runGame)),
                NULL));
```

and add this method.

```
void CCSplashLayer::runGame(){
     auto scene = HelloWorld::createScene();
     Director::getInstance()->setDepthTest(true);
     TransitionScene *transition = TransitionScene::create(0.5f, scene);
     Director::getInstance()->pushScene(transition);
}
```

Comment: This will also show i icon in eclipse and show this message on hover *****in expansion of macro 'callfuncN_selector'******

Comment: *-1* this will also give error in Windows and Android compiler. `CCCallFuncN` takes functor having `CCNode*` in argument. Either use `CCCallFunc` or change function `runGame()` to `runGame(CCNode* node)`

Comment: in V2.2 CCCallFuncN is working fine in android. i compiled through eclipse using Mac OSX..

Comment: i dont know about Cocos2dx 3.0 +